# Given sorted list how to create list of integers that wont fall in certain range in O(log(N)) time?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I have a sorted arrayList of integers (no duplicates):

```
{1,2,4,5,8,12,15, 21,23,26,30,32,35,37,40,42,45,48,51,54}
```

Lets say given range is [21-38] (inclusive) which has to be excluded from the output list of integers.

Then the output should contain the list of integers that does not contain the above range.

```
{1,2,4,5,8,12,15,40,42,45,48,51,54}
```

I need to do this in **O(log(N)**) time.

The approaches that i could think of at this moment is:

```
Approach1:
1) Find lower bound index using binary search in O(logN)
2) Find higher bound index using binary search in O(logN)
3) Then loop over the input list and add the integers to new list by 
considering above lower and higher bound index. But this third step takes O(n).

Approach2:

I also feel that the above approach of using binary search is not 
 great as we can directly iterate over original list to remove the 
  integers falling under the range without using binary search.
```

Do we have any better approach?

Comment: There is no way to make new list faster than O(N)

Comment: Not sure if you are doing any data manipulation with output list itself, but if not, you can make this list a linked list and just update tail node's `next` pointer of first set to head pointer of that second list. So, this can be done in logarithmic time. However, this really depends on the future use case of what you are trying to do ahead of returning an output list.

Comment: Thanks Mbo and nice_dev. Looks like there is no way to achieve that using arraylist.

Comment: @SSK Use arrayList on cose O(N)，use linkedList can use O(log(N)) but the code will be  complex so I think O(N) is good。

Comment: @TongChen thanks for the input , i will go with O(N) approach2 ,

Comment: It could be filtered on iteration with a wrapper - the iteration is also O(N). the way its formulated - creation or iteration always drives to a O(n) algorithm. It should be more explicit on a usage case and the gain expected for many iteration and one writing, or the opposite.

Comment: @SSK the only thing you can do in O(logN) here is find the range of indexes that you need to exclude in the output list

Comment: @AbhinavMathur thanks for confirmation. I was just wondering if we have some better way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing of elements may be optimized for better cases by estimating a better option by the size of the remainder and removal:

```java
static List<Integer> removeFrom(List<Integer> sorted, int sv, int ev) {
    int i1 = Collections.binarySearch(sorted, sv);
    int i2 = Collections.binarySearch(sorted, ev);
    int from, to;
    if (i1 < i2) {
        from = i1;
        to = i2;
    } else {
        from = i2;
        to = i1;
    }
    System.out.printf("Removing values %d..%d%n", sv, ev);
    int size = sorted.size();
    int removeLength = to - from + 1;
    int remainLength = size - removeLength;
    if (removeLength < remainLength) {
        System.out.printf("Removing range: [%d, %d]%n", from, to);
        sorted.removeAll(sorted.subList(from, to + 1));
        return sorted;
    } else {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (from > 0) {
            System.out.printf("Keeping head: [%d, %d]%n", 0, from);
            result.addAll(sorted.subList(0, from));
        }
        if (to < size - 1) {
            System.out.printf("Keeping tail: [%d, %d]%n", to, size);
            result.addAll(sorted.subList(to + 1, size));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Tests:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {1, 3},
    {7, 10},
    {3, 6},
    {2, 10},
    {1, 9},
    {2, 9}
};
for (int[] test : tests) {
    List<Integer> sorted = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("result: " + removeFrom(sorted, test[0], test[1]) + "\n====\n");
}
```

Output

```
Removing values 1..3
Removing range: [0, 2]
result: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
====

Removing values 7..10
Removing range: [6, 9]
result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
====

Removing values 3..6
Removing range: [2, 5]
result: [1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
====

Removing values 2..10
Keeping head: [0, 1]
result: [1]
====

Removing values 1..9
Keeping tail: [8, 10]
result: [10]
====

Removing values 2..9
Keeping head: [0, 1]
Keeping tail: [8, 10]
result: [1, 10]
====
```

So, in the *best case* the complexity is O(M), where M is the size of remaining part.